# What Machine Learning model can I use to predict the shape of a polygon using another polygon?

Tags: machine-learning, polygon, shapes

I have a database of individuals in which, each individual has two polygons with different numbers of vertices and shapes, I would like to use one polygon's information to predict the shape of the second polygon. Which Machine Learning technique can I use for this? I have been looking on the internet but I have found no good answer yet.

Thanks for the help

I have tried looking on the internet, as I do not have any idea of which model to use

Answer (score -1):

This sounds more like a supervised learning problem. Try using information of your first polygon as feature and the shape of the second polygon as label.